# unit test render an exception into an HTTP response?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5.4

How to test if `render()` an exception into an HTTP response working correctly. I want to test without calling `$this->get()`

This is a method in Laravel:

```
  public function render($request, Exception $e)
  {
        $response['exception'] = get_class($e);
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();

        if ($e instanceof LockException) {
            return $this->errorResponse('lock', $response, 'Lock error has occurred', $e->getCode());
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

I need to test if `LockException` has turn into an HTTP response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. In your test, instantiate the controller into a variable, create a blank request and pass in your LockException:

```
$response = $controller->render($request, $exception);
$this->assertEquals('string of HTML you expect', $response);
```

Comment: How do you instantiate a `$controller` ? Where is that declared from

Comment: Same way you instantiate any object! `$controller = new Whatever($possiblyPassingSomethingItNeedsToo);`

Comment: Oh that lol. I need to find a way to mock `\Illuminate\Http\Request` to pass into `render`

Comment: Cant you just create a new one of those? We aren't testing that functionality, just the Exception stuff